# Not receiving any IPN post for sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm using sandbox accounts to test SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckout methods. However, I'm not receiving any IPN notifications.

My PC has public IP and firewall is off, so I'm expecting IPN posts but none are coming. Is there anything I should do (e.g. any profile settings) to start receiving IPN? (I'm using the Java SDK and passing the notify_url as parameter)

I'm also checking the "IPN History Page" from PayPal.com and I do not find any data there. Am I supposed to find IPN data in this page even if I use the sandbox accounts?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I solved the problem by transfering my code to another server. something must have been wrong with my public IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have IPN enabled in your test Sandbox PayPal account.  Also, you will not see IPN messages in your PayPal account if you are going to www.paypal.com.  This would only be for live IPN messages sent through your live account.  If you are wanting to see the IPN messages for your sandbox transactions, you would need to log into the sandbox seller account and view the IPN messages from there.

Comment: Thanks Chad. Can you tell me how to enable IPN in sandbox account i.e. do I need to enable it even if I'm passing the notify_url? I can see IPN messages sent, but all of them failed after 8 retries! There are no HTML response code shown as well. My IPN handler is publicly accessible, so why PayPal is failing to make POST request to it?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs/error logs to see if anything is getting triggered in there?  What port are you going through?  443?